# Computer hangs at GNU GRUB

Tags: grub2

I have setup Ubuntu server 14.04 and its been working fine for some time not until yesterday when i start my computer.
It is stuck on the GNU Grub.
I can't even use my keyboard.
I know the keyboard is working because i can use it on BIOS setup.

What should I do?